# Calculating mean in R (column from dataset)

Tags: r, mean

I am trying to calculate the mean from a column in a dataset I have. This is the following code.

```
ATLANTA = complete_dataset %>% 
  filter(club == "ATL") %>% 
  select(base_salary)

ATL = mean(ATLANTA)
print(ATL)
```

I get the following error:

> In mean.default(ATLANTA) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

However, the data type in the data set is numeric.

Comment: Try using `pull()` instead of select.  The dplyr code turns everything to tibbles.  Or instead do ` %>% summarize(mean = mean(base_salary))

Comment: `ATLANTA` is not numeric. It's a tibble that just happens to have one column. The column values may be numeric, but the tibble container is not. You cannot take the `mean` of a tibble.